# "Dependent and independent variables" in first order logic?

Tags: terminology, first-order-logic

In calculus, students are taught the notion of "[dependent and independent variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_and_independent_variables)" of a function. (I am not talking about "independent" random variables in probability theory.) In first-order logic, there is a notion of "[free and bound variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables)".

Are these two notions somehow related? If not, does the first notion of "variables" fit in any concept in first-order logic?

Background: I do not have any expert knowledge in first-order logic.

Comment: The concept of dependent and independent variables is more intrinsic to the sciences (and mathematical modelling in general) than to calculus, in which case the independent variables refer to the function's input variables while the dependent variables are its output variables. For example, when discussing the force field around a magnet, the independent variables are the three spatial coordinates, while the dependent variables are the three components of the force vector.

Comment: On the other hand, in first-order logic, formulae depend on both their free and bound variables, and a formula is open (i.e., a predicate) if it contains a free variable, and closed (i.e., a sentence/proposition) otherwise.

Comment: also: free variables versus leading variables in linear algebra...